# Spring MVC REST Web services: post from PHP using JSON

Tags: php, json, web-services, post, spring-mvc

So I have a working Spring MVC 3 application with a layer of services I need to turn into a layer of RESTful Web services.

After a few researches, I found it was really easy to do GET Web services using annotations. But I still can't find a relevant POST example from something else than Java.

So, to make things "simple" let's take this generic controller:

```
public abstract class GenericControllerImpl<T, F extends GenericForm> implements GenericController<T, F> {

    protected String name;
    protected String root;
    protected GenericService<T, F> service;

    public GenericControllerImpl(final String root, final String name, final GenericService<T, F> service) {
        this.root = root;
        this.name = name;
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String defaultHome(final Model model) {
        this.loadEntities(model);
        this.populateLists(model);
        return this.root;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String display(@PathVariable final int id, final Model model) {
        this.loadEntityContext(model, id);
        return "display" + this.name;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayCreate(final Model model) {
        this.loadCreateContext(model);
        this.populateLists(model);

        return "create" + this.name;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createAction(@Valid @ModelAttribute("createForm") final F form, final BindingResult result, final Model model) {

        try {
            if (!result.hasErrors()) {
                this.service.create(form);
                return "redirect:/" + this.root + '/';
            } else {
                this.populateLists(model);
                return "create" + this.name;
            }
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            this.populateLists(model);
            this.loadErrorContext(model, exception);
            return "create" + this.name;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteAction(final Model model, @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) final int id) {

        try {
            this.service.deleteFromId(id);
            return "redirect:/" + this.root + '/';
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            this.loadErrorContext(model, exception);
            return this.root;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load all the entities of the entity type handled by the controller into the context model.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            the context model
     */
    protected void loadEntities(final Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("list", this.service.list());
    }

    /**
     * Load a specific entity into the context model.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            the context model
     * @param id
     *            the id of the entity to load
     */
    protected T loadEntity(final Model model, final int id) {
        T item = this.service.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("item", item);
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Load a specific entity context into the context model. By default it loads only the entity but for some entities, some other
     * entities might be useful.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            the context model
     * @param id
     *            the id of the entity to load
     */
    protected void loadEntityContext(final Model model, final int id) {
        this.loadEntity(model, id);
    }

    /**
     * Populate the lists of the other entities referenced by the current entity.
     * 
     * @param model
     *            the context model
     */
    protected abstract void populateLists(Model model);
}
```

So a simple method such as `display` would give something like this (if I got it):

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public T display(@PathVariable final int id) {
    return this.service.findById(id);
}
```

But how could I change the method `createAction` ?

Note that this is a generic controller which all the controllers extend. It would be awesome if this could stay this way, but if it's not possible then I'll do what's needed of course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Though is bit late to answer, here is my code. You can find good explanation [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody.html).

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
Transaction createTransaction(MyModel myModel,
        @RequestParam("secKey") String secKey) {

    log.debug(" create MyModel {}", mymodel);
    return new MyModel();

}
```

I think you should have another look at your delete operation. It uses post request and it is better if you can use, put or delete.